# why still need to input a password when using fastlane match nuke

Tags: fastlane

Now I forget the fastlane match password, I did not have any way to find out what is the password. So I want to reset the password using this command(I get this way from https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/6297):

```
fastlane match nuke distribution
```

but still tell me to input the `Passphrase for Match storage`:

```
$ fastlane match nuke distribution                                                                                                                             ‹ruby-2.7.2›
[✔] 
[12:21:55]: fastlane detected a Gemfile in the current directory
[12:21:55]: However, it seems like you didn't use `bundle exec`
[12:21:55]: To launch fastlane faster, please use
[12:21:55]:
[12:21:55]: $ bundle exec fastlane match nuke distribution
[12:21:55]:
[12:21:55]: Get started using a Gemfile for fastlane https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile
[12:21:56]: In the config file './fastlane/Matchfile' you have the line git_url, but didn't provide any value. Make sure to append a value right after the option name. Make sure to check the docs for more information
[12:21:56]: In the config file './fastlane/Matchfile' you have the line username, but didn't provide any value. Make sure to append a value right after the option name. Make sure to check the docs for more information
[12:21:56]: Successfully loaded '/Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/flutter-netease-music/ios/fastlane/Matchfile' 

+-----------------+---------------------------+
| Detected Values from './fastlane/Matchfile' |
+-----------------+---------------------------+
| git_branch      | master                    |
| storage_mode    | git                       |
| type            | adhoc                     |
| app_identifier  | ["com.reddwarf.musicapp"] |
+-----------------+---------------------------+

Available session is not valid any more. Continuing with normal login.
[12:21:59]: To not be asked about this value, you can specify it using 'git_url'
[12:21:59]: URL to the git repo containing all the certificates: https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/music-certificate.git
[12:22:19]: Cloning remote git repo...
[12:22:19]: If cloning the repo takes too long, you can use the `clone_branch_directly` option in match.
[12:22:21]: Checking out branch master...
[12:22:21]: Enter the passphrase that should be used to encrypt/decrypt your certificates
[12:22:21]: This passphrase is specific per repository and will be stored in your local keychain
[12:22:21]: Make sure to remember the password, as you'll need it when you run match on a different machine
[12:22:21]: Passphrase for Match storage: ******
[12:22:31]: Type passphrase again: ******
[12:22:33]: wrong final block length
[12:22:33]: Couldn't decrypt the repo, please make sure you enter the right password!
keychain: "/Users/dolphin/Library/Keychains/jiangxiaoqiang-db"
version: 512
class: "inet"
attributes:
    0x00000007 <blob>="match_https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/music-certificate.git"
    0x00000008 <blob>=<NULL>
    "acct"<blob>=<NULL>
    "atyp"<blob>="dflt"
    "cdat"<timedate>=0x32303231303831383034323233335A00  "20210818042233Z\000"
    "crtr"<uint32>=<NULL>
    "cusi"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "desc"<blob>=<NULL>
    "icmt"<blob>=<NULL>
    "invi"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "mdat"<timedate>=0x32303231303831383034323233335A00  "20210818042233Z\000"
    "nega"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "path"<blob>=<NULL>
    "port"<uint32>=0x00000000
    "prot"<blob>=<NULL>
    "ptcl"<uint32>=0x00000000
    "scrp"<sint32>=<NULL>
    "sdmn"<blob>=<NULL>
    "srvr"<blob>="match_https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/music-certificate.git"
    "type"<uint32>=<NULL>
password has been deleted.
[12:22:33]: Enter the passphrase that should be used to encrypt/decrypt your certificates
[12:22:33]: This passphrase is specific per repository and will be stored in your local keychain
[12:22:33]: Make sure to remember the password, as you'll need it when you run match on a different machine
[12:22:33]: Passphrase for Match storage:
```

I really did not remember the password, I just remember the password I was set the password is very simple, but after I input it tell me incorrect. what should I do to reset the password or find the password? I have tried to delete all certificate files to regerneate the certificate info but still need to input `Passphrase for Match storage`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a *new git repo* and update your **Matchfile** with that newly created repo URL.
Then you should be able to run without entering any Passphrase

> bundle exec fastlane match nuke distribution

Please feel free to open discussion here, if you still having issue
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/discussions